# How can a user sign out of Owin External Authentication and sign back in as another user?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, owin

Using Owin External Authentication in an MVC application, how can a user Sign Out of my application and sign back in with a different external account?  AuthenticationManager.SignOut() successfully signs the user out of my application, however, if they visit the external login page again they are just instantly signed back in as the same user.

In a system where one person may have multiple external accounts, how can this be accomplished without having to close the browser? Are there some sort of Cookie or authentication options that will let the user choose a different account on the external sign in page?

Comment: Do you use any cookie middleware in your application (startup.cs)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the Authentication Type in the Sign Out method, otherwise only the browser cookie will be destroyed.

If the user could have multiple external logins, you can loop through the Authentication Types you have configured in your `Startup.Auth.cs` and add them to a list that is then provided to the `AuthenticationManager SignOut` method.

```
var authTypes = AuthManager.GetAuthenticationTypes().ToList();
var authTypeNames = new List<string>();

foreach (var authType in authTypes)
{
    if (!authTypeNames.Contains(authType.AuthenticationType))
                authTypeNames.Add(authType.AuthenticationType);
}

AuthManager.SignOut(authTypeNames.ToArray());
```

Here I am getting all Authentication Types from the Authorisation Manager (I'm using AutoFac to get the instances provided to the controller). Since this method gives you several duplicate authentication types (eg. Bearer) I am looping the types and adding each distinct one to a list. I then convert the list to an array and call the Authentication Manager `SignOut` method which will sign the user out of all authentication types, including local and external cookies, and external providers.